# How to monitor system calls of Mac OS X system services with dtruss?

Tags: macos, system-calls

I am trying to see which applications are accessing some system services on Mac OS X.

For example plan was to monitor pboard daemon and see which application sent data or received data from it.

I expected to see system calls to Mach Ports but nothing exciting happened.

```
# dtruss -n pboard
```

or

```
# dtruss -p <PID of pboard>
```

yielded nothing or some message about disconnected client appeared which may not be produced by dtrace itself.

After few tries pasteboard stopped functioning and copy-paste stopped working.

What went wrong, and why dtrace can monitor any other process except pboard I have no idea.

How can I make dtrace successfully monitor pboard?